# Get new image using image crop library of Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagelibrary

I want to get the file name of new image created using the image crop library in Codeigniter and save it in a mysql database.

This is my current cropping code:

```
$data['x'] = $this->input->post('x1');
$data['y'] = $this->input->post('y1');
$data['w'] = $this->input->post('width');
$data['h'] = $this->input->post('height');

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = 'assets/images/supplier_photos/'.$this->input->post('img_file');
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['new_image'] = './assets/images/supplier_photos/crop/'.$this->input->post('img_file');
$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
$config['width']  = $data['w'];
$config['height'] = $data['h'];
$config['x_axis'] = $data['x'];
$config['y_axis'] = $data['y'];

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

if(!$this->image_lib->crop())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}  
$this->suppliers_model->update_photos();
```

Now I want to get the file name of the new image created. How can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried? This question is currently too broad to provide an answer.

Comment: Please check, i update the question and include the codes. thanks!

Comment: It looks like your `$config` array already has `new_image` set to `'./assets/images/supplier_photos/crop/'.$this->input->post('img_file')`. Is the file appearing there? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors, the new image is created. But i want to get its file name only so that I can store in database.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the image is stored in the POST value of `img_file`. You can access it via `$this->input->post('img_file')` (in fact your configuration is concatenating that to the path). You can assign this to a variable like this:

```
$file_name = $this->input->post('img_file');
```

You can then use `$file_name` wherever you would like to use the actual file name without the path.